# OpenGL over ssh

Tags: ssh, x11, macintosh, opengl

My problem is about running OpenGL via `ssh`. When I execute `glxgears` on my office workstation (when I am physically present in the office), it works normally. But when I connect to the office workstation via `ssh -X` from my laptop (I am using a macbook and Xquartz) `glxgears` does open up but the gears don't move.

There is another program written pyOpenGL that I want to execute remotely. It works perfectly when executed on the office workstation. But when I try to run it by connecting to the workstation from a macbook, it shows the following error:

```
pygame.error: Could not create GL context
```

I noticed something else as well: The output of `glxinfo` on the office workstation is different from the output of `glxinfo` when executed on the workstation after connecting to it via `ssh`.

Output of `glxinfo` after connecting to it via `ssh`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 INTEL-16.1.7)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Output of `glxinfo` when executed on the workstation:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce RTX 2070/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 450.66
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Different? Can you show?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the exact outputs

Comment: So it works with `OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66` and fails with `OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 INTEL-16.1.7)`?

Comment: But why are there two different versions of OpenGL. Both instances of `glxinfo` are executed on the same workstation - one remotely and the other not

Comment: `glxinfo` retrieves that information from the X _server_, and you're using two different servers.  Where `glxinfo` is running is unimportant.

Comment: Is it possible to use the OpenGL version and hardware of the remote workstation (the X client, I assume) and display the results on my notebook (X server). Based on what you say, I assume that when I execute my program on the remote workstation, after connecting to it via ssh, it uses the opengl version on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

> But when I connect to the office workstation via ssh -X from my laptop (I am using a macbook and Xquartz) glxgears does open up but the gears don't move.

That's because the X protocol doesn't always work for OpenGL, which can require shared buffers in memory and other things.

You need something like [VirtualGL](https://virtualgl.org/Main/HomePage) to make this happen, and they actually have a good explanation on the [background](https://virtualgl.org/About/Background).